# android actionbar unit test using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android

I am writing a unit test for actionbar navigation in my android app. There are two tabs (home and mentions). The home tab should bring up the home fragment and the mentions tab should bring up the mentions fragment. I am using the fragmentmanager to get the current fragment in the activity and then using instanceof to see if they belong to the right class.

```
 @UiThreadTest
    public void testNavigationBar() {
        assertEquals(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, actionBar.getNavigationMode());
        assertEquals(2, actionBar.getNavigationItemCount());

        Tab tab0 = actionBar.getTabAt(0);
        assertNotNull(tab0);
        assertNotNull(tab0.getText());
        assertEquals(mActivity.getBaseContext().getString(R.string.navigation_home), tab0.getText());

        Tab tab1 = actionBar.getTabAt(1);
        assertNotNull(tab1);
        assertNotNull(tab1.getText());
        assertEquals(mActivity.getBaseContext().getString(R.string.navigation_mention),
                tab1.getText());

        FragmentManager sfm = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();

        actionBar.selectTab(tab0);
        assertEquals(0, actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex());
        Fragment currentFragment = sfm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);
        assertNotNull(currentFragment);
        assertTrue(currentFragment instanceof HomeTimeLineFragment);

        actionBar.selectTab(tab1);
        assertEquals(1, actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex());
        Log.d(tag, String.valueOf(actionBar.getSelectedTab().getText()));
        currentFragment = sfm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameContainer);
        assertNotNull(currentFragment);
        assertTrue(currentFragment instanceof MentionsFragment);
    }
```

The test fails as the currentFragment is still an instanceof HomeTimeLineFragment. Btw the log.d statement prints out "Mentions". So the mentions tab is definitely selected in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
sfm.executePendingTransactions();
```

after

```
actionBar.selectTab(tab1);
```