# Android unit test actionbar with tabs and fragments

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-actionbar, fragment

i am trying to write an unit test for an Activity which uses the ActionBar in the tab-mode.
in the tab listener of my Activity i am replacing the current fragment with another fragment (MyListFragment, MyContentFragment)
In my simple unit test i want to check if the right fragments are shown when clicking the corresponding tab.

My unit test looks like this.

```
public class TestMyActivity
    extends android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity>

   @Override
   protected void setUp() throws Exception
   {
       super.setUp();
       this.activity = getActivity();
   }

   @UiThreadTest
   public void testSelectContentTab()
   {
       ActionBar actionBar = this.activity.getActionBar();
       Tab tab_list = actionBar.getTabAt(0);
       Tab tab_content = actionBar.getTabAt(1);
       actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

       assertEquals(1, actionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex());

       FragmentManager fm = this.activity.getFragmentManager();
       Fragment currentFragment =
       fm.findFragmentById(resourceIdOfTab_navigation_fragment_container);
       assertTrue(currentFragment instanceof MyContentFragment);
    }
}
```

The test fails because the currentFragment is not an instance of MyContentFragment as expected but an instance of MyListFragment althoug the test for the selectedNavigationIndex works fine.
Can anyone please help or have any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach is using robotium testing framework.
See also answer in [android actionbar unit test using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472073/android-actionbar-unit-test-using-activityinstrumentationtestcase2/21989462#21989462)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
this.activity.getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

after

```
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
```